# What's a good strategy for an open source project to not share production settings?

Tags: version-control, mercurial, open-source

I'm currently looking to release an MVC / RavenDB as an open source repository mostly just to let people look around rather than as a full on project.

However I don't want certain production settings such as SMTP Server details and Connection Strings publicly exposed (but still under source control).

I'm looking for suggestions on how I should structure public and private repositories so that I can easily work on the project and have reasonably hassle free deployment.

Cheers

Comment: won't having a private branch of this work? then you can upadte the open version with pull requests?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In cases similar to yours where I need to publish parts publicly and keep import data hidden, I usually very simply keep a branch only for production.

[image]

In your case, you could either make the dev branch where you publishing everything open source, clone it and receive some contributions from other people. Then have a production branch somewhere different. (heroku..)

Answer (score 1):

You normally don't put those files under version control. Inside a company, say, you can put a *template* under version control and ask your developers to copy it into place and update as necessary. Like a `config.ini.template` file with

```
[smtp]
host = smtp.company.com
user = USERNAME # update this
pass = PASSWORD # and this
```

where it's clear that the developers need to update the credentials when they rename it to `config.ini`. The `config.ini` file should then be excluded from version control.

For an open source project I would probably not put any template under version control. I would still configure it so that the `config.ini` file is excluded from version control so that I can have my own `config.ini` file in my working copy without committing it by accident.

I find the above system much easier than putting the real config files under version control. Even if I can put it in a private branch of some sort, then it will require me to constantly merge with that branch and I'll have to be careful not to accidentally push the config file to another repository.

Comment: +1 for template configs under VC